# Problems after moving my project from Azure sdk 1.8.0.0 to 2.0.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, azure

I am moving my project from Azure sdk 1.8.0.0 to 2.0.0.0

It works fine in development environment but when i am going to deploy this on Azure portal  it gives me error. shown below

```
An unhandled exception occurred. Type: System.IO.FileNotFoundException Process ID: 3620
Process Name: WaIISHost
Thread ID: 5
AppDomain Unhandled Exception for role Frontend_IN_0
Exception: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at DiagConfig.Config.GetRoleInstanceDiagMonitor()
   at Frontend.WebRole.OnStart()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.InitializeRoleInternal(RoleType roleTypeEnum)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.Implementation.Loader.RoleRuntimeBridge.<InitializeRole>b__0()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Can you please help in this?

Comment: You maybe need an update in your web.config to point to the 'new' assembly.

Comment: What about searching for "1.8" in all files in your working subfolder? That way you'll find the reference you failed to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably updated your cloud project to version 2.0 , but the project that you are going to deploy to Azure still have their references to the old Azure 1.8

Try searching for all 1.8 references, if you are using nuget you could do a "*manage nuget packages for solution*" by right-clicking the solution file and update all your azure references to the latest.